# Generating band-limited NRZ signal

Tags: software-defined-radio, signal-synthesis, electrical-signal

What is the bandwidth of a NRZ signal (of a given frequency) and how would you directly synthesize a discrete version a band-limited NRZ signal at some higher sample rate?

Comment: Well you would have to carefully define bandwidth. What is the purpose of your question? Homework? What does the Fourier transform of an NRZ pulse look like?

Comment: @DanBoschen Personal edification, not school work. By bandwidth, I mean the minimum bandwidth required to recover the data.

Comment: @DanBoschen I imagine the FFT of the NRZ signal would look like the combination of many square waves with fundamentals that are integer multiples of the bit-rate. There would be many harmonics going all the way to Nyquist.

Comment: You say Nyquist but an NRZ signal isn't necessarily sampled--- do you see what it would be for a continuous time signal? That may be helpful to picture first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first concept that I think will be helpful to see is pulse shapes that repeat in time at consistent rates. If you repeat a fundamental pulse shape in time, the result in frequency will have the envelope of the Fourier Transform for that pulse but will only contain frequency components at multiples of the repetition rate (harmonics).  Thus the Fourier Transform becomes sampled in frequency at multiples of the repetition rate in time. For example see the cases below for NRZ signals with different duty cycles, knowing that the Fourier Transform of a square pulse is a Sinc function in frequency with the first null at $1/T$ where T is the width of the pulse.

[image: 50 % duty cycle]

[image: 25 % duty cycle]

Now consider what occurs if the NRZ data has a pulse width of 0.05 seconds like the first example but is a random pattern 101101110001... that doesn't repeat for 10 seconds - the envelope will still be the same as the first example with the first null at 20 Hz, but the harmonics will appear every 0.1 Hz, the spectrum will appear continuous. Extend this thought to random data that never repeats and the spectrum will indeed be continuous with the same shape.

So to answer your question the bandwidth of an NRZ pulse is infinite, but the bandwidth of any time limited pulse will be infinite if you review the Fourier Transform equations. However for practical considerations we can define bandwidth to be % of power within a certain frequency band, or ignoring spectral content that gets below a certain insignificant value.

With that in mind, the bandwidth of a Sinc pulse in frequency (NRZ signal in time) is still quite large, since the peaks of the Sinc only roll-off at rate f in frequency (or 20 dB/decade).  By shaping the pulse edges in time (slowing the transition rate), we can significantly limit the bandwidth.

A common approach is to reverse the case of the NRZ signal above, and use time-limited versions of the Sinc function in time as the fundamental pulse, in such a way that the null crossings of the Sinc are aligned with the centers of a subsequent pulses (for zero inter-symbol inteference while getting the frequency limiting abilities of the Sinc pulse). The longer you can make the Sinc pulse in duration, the tighter the bandwidth as in the extreme of an infinitely long Sinc in time would result in a brick-wall spectrum in frequency.

This is demonstrated clearly in this graphic below, for a muli-level PAM waveform (Or what it actually is, is the real part of a 16-QAM waveform). Regardless the fundamental pulse shape for the blue line is a rectangular NRZ pulse in time, and the blue spectrum shown is what I was explaining above for the case or random non-repeating data.

The red line is the "Raised-Cosine" pulse shape which is a Sinc pulse that has an additional taper given by a "raised cosine" (see additional graphic on that). But notably see how significantly more constrained the resulting red spectrum becomes and hence the pulse-shaped waveform is more spectrally efficient. We go through the extra effort to shape the pulse in order to conserve spectrum.

[image: pulse shaping]

[image: raised cosine pulse shaping]

[image: Pulse Shaping multiple symbols]

Comment: Is your example of pulse shaping basically the same thing as Lanczos resampling? It looks identical.

Comment: Well the same in that they both use modified Sinc functions, but Sinc functions show up for lots of different reasons. With the Lanczos that is used for interpolation specifically, since a Sinc function provides ideal interpolation. This is a different application of the Sinc function here but for similar reasons.

Comment: Did this help answer your original question? This is the underlying continuous time waveform that you would create, and sampling this would now be trivial-- in practical application this is implemented with pulse shaping filters-- so your data symbols are represented by impulses and the pulse shape is in the filter--each impulse produces an impulse response and in this way all the pulses overlap the way we want them to. That may be helpful to know as well if you are implementing this in an SDR.

Comment: I believe it does. I've made an example on Desmos which I believe is correct... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bfr6ymtyv7

Comment: Yes that absolutely looks correct, and thanks for the heads up on desmos, haven't heard of it before but looks convenient.